# Не понял как так вышло, объясните, если не сложно. Спасибо

Tags: javascript

```js
var power = function(base, exponent) {
  var result = 1;
  for (var count = 0; count < exponent; count++)
    result *= base;
  return result;
};

console.log(power(2, 10));
// → 1024
```

Comment: а что вам непонятно? поставьте печать result в цикле, наверное, станет еще понятнее

Comment: а что вышло-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для наглядности выводим не конечный результат, а промежуточный на каждой итерации:

```js
var power = function(base, exponent) {
  var result = 1;
  for (var count = 0; count < exponent; count++) {
    result *= base;
    console.log(result);
  }
};
power(2, 10);
```

То есть у нас 10 итераций (пока count < exponent), и на каждой мы в result записываем произведение result*base. Сначала result = 1*2. Затем 2*2 и т.д. В итоге получаем 1024.

Comment: можете сказать чему равно base? Если result 1, то если умножить на base, то ничего не будет вроде. Так как вышло 2 и дальше? Заранее благодарю

Comment: @Мастер_Программирования, base Вы сами задали при вызове функции - 2. Вы в первой итерации 1 умножаете на 2. Получается 2. Дальше 4 и т.д.

Comment: @Мастер_Программирования 1 умножается на 2 10 раз. То есть 1 умножается на 2 в 10 степени. То есть 1 умножается на 1024. 1 * 1024 = 1024.

Comment: @MironsaysreinstateRedStar, я же специально вывел в консоль результат каждого умножения. Какое 1 на 1024?

Comment: @humster_spb да я же не про ваш ответ. Ему, видимо, непонятен момент с умножением на единицу

Comment: @Мастер_Программирования,  на начало выполнения кода у вас base = 2; result = 1; цикл выполняет 10 итераций; 1 итерация   result =  1* 2 будет 2 эта 2 сохраняется в result ; 2 итерация result =  2 * 2 будет 4 эта 4 сохраняется в result  и так будет выполняться 10 итераций в итоге  result будет равен 1024